# Oracle: how to run this query (generated column names)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to run a query on generated generated column names.

Here's the query:

```
select 'col_'||4 from  MY_TABLE
```

Note:

1. "4" is a variable that is passed to this query from within the Java code
2. MY_TABLE is a table that contain columns with names (col_4, col_5, etc..)

Comment: A table with column names that contain incrementing numbers sounds like you actually want to re-think your DB-design

Comment: Actually it is already-exist table. and I think it is regenerated by DBAs everywhere when database get updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside Oracle you need use dynamic SQL. (YourVariable value is 4 for your example)

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' select col_' || YourVariable  || ' from  MY_TABLE ';
```

From Java you can build any SQL and execute them

Comment: I think I was very idiot to ask such question :), BTW, I'll test your recommendation and come back accept your answer :)

Comment: This statement runs. But the selected data is not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

To run a dynamic SELECT statement, you have two choices:

For single row selects, you use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ... INTO:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select col_' || l_num  || ' from  MY_TABLE WHERE id = 37' INTO l_result;
```

For selecting multiple rows, you can use a dynamic cursor:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE MyCurType IS REF CURSOR;
   my_cv   MyCurType;
BEGIN
   OPEN emp_cv FOR 'select col_' || l_num  || ' from  MY_TABLE';
   ...
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

This code generates a SELECT that returns the tables with their column name:

```
SELECT
'SELECT ' ||(
    SELECT
        LISTAGG(
            c.TABLE_NAME || '.' || c.COLUMN_NAME || ' AS "' || c.TABLE_NAME || '.' || c.COLUMN_NAME || '"',
            ', '
        ) WITHIN GROUP(
        ORDER BY
            c.TABLE_NAME
        ) "TABLE_NAMES"
    FROM
        USER_TAB_COLS c
    WHERE
        TABLE_NAME IN(
            'PESSOA',
            'PESSOA_FISICA',
            'PESSOA_JURIDICA'
        )
)|| 'FROM PERSON;'
FROM
  DUAL;
```